# Python multiple pivot from the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with just one column with content like:

```
view: meta_record_extract
dimension: e_filter
type: string
hidden: yes
sql: "SELECT * FROM files"
dimension: category
type: string
...
```

What I tried to produce would be a dataframe with columns and the data like this:

```
____________________________________________________________________    
view                    | dimension |label | type  | hidden | sql      |
     meta_record_extract| e_filter  | NaN  | string| yes    |"SELECT * FROM files" 
NaN                     | category  | NaN  | string ...
```

Given that splitting the string data like

```
df.header[0].split(': ')[0]
```

was giving me label with [0] or value with [1]
I tried this:

```
df.pivot_table(df, columns = df.header.str.split(': ')[0], values = df.header.str.split(': ')[1])
```

but it did not work giving the error.

Can anyone help me to achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) + [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), as follows:

[`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) helps you extract the keyword and value pairs into a list.  We then map the list of keyword-value pairs into a dict for [`pd.Dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to turn the dict into a dataframe.

(Assuming the column label of your column is `Col1`):

```
df_extract = df['Col1'].str.findall(r'(\w+):\s*(.*)')

df_result = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, df_extract))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_result)



                  view dimension    type hidden                    sql
0  meta_record_extract       NaN     NaN    NaN                    NaN
1                  NaN  e_filter     NaN    NaN                    NaN
2                  NaN       NaN  string    NaN                    NaN
3                  NaN       NaN     NaN    yes                    NaN
4                  NaN       NaN     NaN    NaN  "SELECT * FROM files"
5                  NaN  category     NaN    NaN                    NaN
6                  NaN       NaN  string    NaN                    NaN
```

#### Update

To compress the rows to minimize the `NaN`'s, we can further use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), as follows:

```
df_compressed = df_result.apply(lambda x:  pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_compressed)


                  view dimension    type hidden                    sql
0  meta_record_extract  e_filter  string    yes  "SELECT * FROM files"
1                  NaN  category  string    NaN                    NaN
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks! And is there a way to align it in one row without extra NaNs?
So the first line would be:
     meta_record_extract| e_filter  | NaN  (there is no label here) | string| yes    |"SELECT * FROM files"

Comment: @RandyMcKay  We can do that. But since you can have some keywords appear more than once and some others only once, it's inevitable that it still leave with some `NaN`.  Anyway, we can minimize that.    Will edit the solution for that.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @RandyMcKay  See my edit above.

Comment: amazing! Thank you a lot!

Comment: sorry, and is there a way to preserve the ordering from df_result data frame? In df_compressed it grouped all the views at the top. I see the dimensions for the first view is below under the other views now. Sorry for bothering...

Comment: @RandyMcKay  Sorry, not quite understand what you mean, especially the statement `I see the dimensions for the first view is below under the other views now.`.  Can you elaborate ?  Is that related to data not in the sample data ?

Comment: in the df, there is a view meta_record_extract with its 2 dimensions: e_filter and category. In the full df there are many other views, so for some reason they are grouped at the top and the category dimension from meta_record_extract is getting listed after all the views.
In other words, df_result has the right ordering, but going to df_compressed the ordering is lost as it groups all the views first.

Comment: @RandyMcKay  Try this and let me know the result:  `df_compressed = df_result.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x, key=pd.isna)).dropna())`

Comment: It is the same as the previous one.
view dimension    type hidden                    sql
view1 dimension type hidden sql
view2 dimension type hidden sql
view3...
Nan category

Comment: maybe set index for int column, reset it and when doing lambda, apply its sorting?

Comment: @RandyMcKay Let me clarify a bit more.  Is the relative sequence within one particular column retained or shuffled ?  I mean within one particular column, not between columns.   This kind of compression is working on column by column.  It simply ignore relative sequence between columns.

Comment: It is shuffled now. First there comes the group of records having views column then starting with nan for views and having dimensions. 
The ordering at df_result level was correct. But after applying lambda it got shuffled.

Comment: @RandyMcKay  Let's consider only one column.  Let's say view.  For its values in df_result, assume 3 values in sequence view1, view2, view3.  You mean after compression, it becomes e.g. view1, view3, view2 ?   Is that true ?  If true, it's weird.  As the `sorted` function I just gave you provides `stable sort`, that's mean, it will maintain sequence.

Comment: in df_result it is view1 on line 1 then view2 on line say 40 and view3 on line 100.
with category (belonging to view1) on line2.
In df_compressed view1, view2 and view3 come as lines 1, 2 and 3. and category dimension coming 4th.

Comment: @RandyMcKay  So you are talking across columns, not within the same column ?  As you said, view column remain as view1, view2, view3, then the sequence is kept.  Sorry, I got confused now.  So, what's the problem ?   As I said, this kind of compression can't handle relationship across columns.

Comment: @RandyMcKay  Is that the problem because compression column does not have entries float to the top ?  Only to the 4th entry topmost ?

Comment: @RandyMcKay  Is that one row in your column have multiple keywords and values ?   As this is not shown in your sample data here, I just not aware of this possibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238069/discussion-between-seabean-and-randymckay).